# wraptext a hyperlink in a given cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to wraptext in the hyperlink cell, but am unable to get it to work correctly.  I get the "object doesn't support this property" error.  I realize the format is incorrect, but can't find the proper syntax.  If you have a link to a site or suggestion, greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
With wbk.Sheets(1)
Set rngResults = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    bingo = fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngResults, Address:=bingo, SubAddress:=aCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=strJackpot
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WrapText` is used with the range, not the hyperlink or the worksheet, so you need to fully qualify it.

Change the `.WrapText = True` line to the following to make it work:

```
rngResults.WrapText = True
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you Olle!  I'm still getting the hang of VBA, so I appreciate it!